# How to position a JFrame permanently above another?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-instances

The jist of the problem is this: I have two JFrames, lets say a big JFrame Foo and smaller JFrame Baz. I have both open at the same time, is there a way to make Baz never be hidden "behind" Foo? Right now when Baz is "in front" and I click on Foo, Baz disappears behind Foo, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use two JFrames. You are trying to make the "bar" window behave like a dialog, and thus it in fact should be a dialog, a JDialog to be exact, and it should be set up so that its parent window is your "foo" JFrame.

Comment: Thanks, stuff like this is a little new to me :)

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [Java - control Z order of JPanels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763136/java-control-z-order-of-jpanels).

If using a JDialog is not an option (because you need a JFrame) then you could use this to manually define z-order rules.