# ordering image and text in jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, chess

I am attempting to overlay the text on a JButton over an ImageIcon that is behind it. However, when the imageIcon is added, the text dissapears. Is there any way to specify the order in which it displays? 
Below, i have tried to separately add the images and text to see if that would affect it, but no luck.
Can anyone help me out?

```
private void initButtons() {

    int locationX = 0, locationY = 525;

    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            boardArray[x][y] = new ChessButton();
            boardArray[x][y].setSize(75, 75);
            boardArray[x][y].setLocation(locationX, locationY);
            boardArray[x][y].setXAndY(x, y);

            if ((x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 == 1) || (x % 2 == 1 && y % 2 == 0)) {
                boardArray[x][y].setColour("white");
                boardArray[x][y].setIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/white_null_null.png"));

            } else {

                boardArray[x][y].setColour("black");
                boardArray[x][y].setIcon(new ImageIcon("Assets/black_null_null.png"));

            }
//this adds the images in an alternating pattern

            chessFrame.add(boardArray[x][y]);
            locationX = locationX + 75;

        }
        locationX = 0;

        locationY = locationY - 75;

    }

}

void initPieces() {
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {

            if ((x % 2 == 0 && y % 2 == 1) || (x % 2 == 1 && y % 2 == 0)) {
                boardArray[x][y].setFont(new Font("Arial Unicode MS", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                boardArray[x][y].setText("\u2654");//sets a particular chess piece as text, just testing it now.

            } else {

                boardArray[x][y].setFont(new Font("Arial Unicode MS", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                boardArray[x][y].setText("\u2654");//sets a particular chess piece as text, just testing it now.
//this is suposed to overlay the image over the text, but it is not.
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .sleep(however many milliseconds youd like to have it wait)

Comment: @JasonD that would block the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and won't overlay the image, but change it by the text and that's not what OP is asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I see you're calling this method: `boardArray[x][y].setLocation(locationX, locationY);`

`.setLocation(...)` indicates you're using a `null` layout, please read [Null layout is evil](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-java/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html) and [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing) to know why you should avoid its use.

For creating a Chess board, I'd be using [`GridLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html), please read how to use the different [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Now, to overlay text over the icon, you only need to call [`JButton#setHorizontalAlignment(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setHorizontalAlignment(int)) method and pass `SwingConstants.CENTER` as the parameter.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ButtonWithImageAndText {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;
    private Icon icon;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new ButtonWithImageAndText().createAndShowGui());
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        try {
            icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("up.jpg")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        button = new JButton();

        button.setIcon(icon);

        button.setText("Click me!");
        button.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        button.setForeground(Color.RED);

        frame.add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Which gives the following output:

[image]

For your future questions, please read how to make a valid [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue and your best try to solve it yourself, the code I posted is a good example of it, as you can copy-paste it and see the same result as I

Answer (score 0):

Use  the setComponentZOrder(...) method of the Container class. This will enable you to set the Z-index of the components to set them in what ever order you like. Look also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763136/java-control-z-order-of-jpanels)

Comment: Can you explain it more? All the JButtons are within a single jFrame. I dont see how to change the order of the ImageIcon and text on a single JButton without adding text to a brand new JFrame above it. Or I am probably very wrong in how this all works.